# how to send JavaScript variable through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I don't know how i can send two parameters ( l_id and l_title) through below method. I used a file upload plugin and want to send two parameters as well on php file.

Please help me how i can assign my variables values in below code if use double or single quotes around the  variables like below it work but send static name as mentioned in quotes.

```
 formData: { id: "l_id", title: "l_title"},
```

but i want to send dynamic values of variables to php file so i need to use below code that making issue.

```
 formData: { id: l_id, title: l_title},
```

Below is full code of jquery

```
  <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
            $(window).load(function(){
            var l_id = $("#id").val();
            var l_title = $("#title").val();
            });
            var settings = {

                url: "ajax_upload.php",
                method: "POST",
                allowedTypes:"jpg,png,gif,pdf",
                formData: { id: l_id, title: l_title},
                fileName: "imageSource",
                multiple: true,
                onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
                {
                    $("#status").html(data);
                    },
                    afterUploadAll:function()
                    {
                            alert("all images uploaded!!");
                    },
                onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
                {        
                    $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Upload is Failed</font>");
                }
            }
            $("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: why are you using $(window).load inside the $(document).ready function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data: { id: $("#id").val(), title: $("#title").val()}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function onUploadStart like this

```
'onUploadStart':function (file)  {
            $('#js_add_file').uploadify('settings','formData',{
                'id':$("#id").val(),
                'title':$("#title").val()
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
            $(window).load(function(){
            var l_id = $("#id").val();
            var l_title = $("#title").val();
            });
            var settings = {

                url: "ajax_upload.php",
                method: "POST",
                allowedTypes:"jpg,png,gif,pdf",
                data: { id: $("#id").val(), title: $("#title").val()}
                fileName: "imageSource",
                multiple: true,
                onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
                {
                    $("#status").html(data);
                    },
                    afterUploadAll:function()
                    {
                            alert("all images uploaded!!");
                    },
                onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
                {        
                    $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Upload is Failed</font>");
                }
            }
            $("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: +1 For the resolution with presenting full code